# Display value of custom property Solidworks VBA Macro

Tags: vba, solidworks

I want to create a macro which exports the drawing as PDF, in the format: drawing name + title + date.

I created a macro which does exactly what I want when I enter a value for `title`. However in this project I want the `title` to be equal to the part name. Therefore I use this code for the `title` value:

> $PRPSHEET:"SW-File Name(File Name)"

The drawing sheet displays `Title` just fine. However the macro does not work. My macro it does not convert this code to the part name. I cannot figure out why. Any tips?

This is how I get the title:

```
Dim swCustProp As CustomPropertyManager

Function FormatFileLocation() As String

Dim Title As String
Dim bool As Boolean
Dim val As String

bool = swCustProp.Get4("title", True, val, Title) 'title is the name of the 
                                                  'property and has the value: $PRPSHEET:"SW-File Name(File Name)"
end function
```

EDIT:
I tried using both `Title` and `val`, but both give the same faulty result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SOLIDWORKS 2014 or later, you should use swCustProp.Get5().  Get4() is obsolete per their [documentation](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ICustomPropertyManager_members.html).

This code worked for me:

```
Dim swApp As Object
Dim swCustProp As CustomPropertyManager
Dim mde As ModelDocExtension
Dim swModel As ModelDoc2

Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set mde = swModel.Extension
Set swCustProp = mde.CustomPropertyManager("")
Call FormatFileLocation

End Sub

Function FormatFileLocation()

Dim Title As String
Dim bool As Boolean
Dim val As String
Dim resolved As Boolean

bool = swCustProp.Get5("title", True, val, Title, resolved) 'title is the name of the
'property and has the value: $PRPSHEET:"SW-File Name(File Name)"
End Function
```

Here are my drawing custom properties:

[image]

Comment: Please add this string as value `$PRPSHEET:"SW-File Name(File Name)"` You wont be able to get the value which is displayed on your annotation linked to this property... And that was exactly the question.

Comment: @2pietjuh2 Does it evaluate in the custom property Evaluated Value column? It doesn't for me.  It has to do with the fact that you can reference multiple parts or assemblies in a drawing, so how would it know which file name to use if there are more than one in the drawing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading from the custom properties.  You could read it from the active drawing view.

```
Dim swApp As Object
Dim swModel As ModelDoc2
Dim swDraw As DrawingDoc

Sub main()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swDraw = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Call FormatFileLocation

End Sub

Function FormatFileLocation()
    Dim Title As String
    Dim v As View
    Set v = swDraw.ActiveDrawingView
    Set swModel = v.ReferencedDocument
    Title = swModel.GetTitle()
End Function
```